# Como separar registros em blocos para processamento paralelo?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, select

Tenho uma tabela em `SQL Server` que faz o controle de mensagens a serem enviadas e uma rotina em `C#`, configurada em um Cron, que seleciona as mensagens pendentes, faz o envio e marca como enviado.

O que estou implementando é a possibilidade de configurar outras chamadas no Cron para que esse processamento seja feito em paralelo, processando assim um maior volume de registros em menor tempo.

O desafio é na montagem da instrução SQL para que uma chamada não selecione os registros da outra chamada.

Tenho algumas premissas a seguir:

- Não posso alterar a estrutura da tabela, nem criar outras tabelas;
- A quantidade de chamadas deve ser flexível, podendo ser incluídos mais chamadas no Cron conforme a demanda.

O esquema da tabela e a query que tenho é mais ou menos essa:

```
DECLARE @Mensagem TABLE (
    id_mensagem INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    criado_em DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    destinatário VARCHAR(250),
    assunto VARCHAR(250),
    mensagem VARCHAR(MAX),
    enviado_em DATETIME
);

INSERT @Mensagem
    (destinatário, assunto, mensagem)
VALUES
    ('teste1@teste.com', 'Assnto 1 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste2@teste.com', 'Assnto 2 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste3@teste.com', 'Assnto 3 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste4@teste.com', 'Assnto 4 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste5@teste.com', 'Assnto 5 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste6@teste.com', 'Assnto 6 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste7@teste.com', 'Assnto 7 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste8@teste.com', 'Assnto 8 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste9@teste.com', 'Assnto 9 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste10@teste.com', 'Assnto 10 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste11@teste.com', 'Assnto 11 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste12@teste.com', 'Assnto 12 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste13@teste.com', 'Assnto 13 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste14@teste.com', 'Assnto 14 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste15@teste.com', 'Assnto 15 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum');

-- Seleciona os registros não enviados
SELECT
    M.id_mensagem,
    M.criado_em,
    M.destinatário,
    M.assunto,
    M.mensagem,
    M.enviado_em
FROM
    @Mensagem AS M
WHERE
    M.enviado_em IS NULL;

-- Após o envio pela rotina C#, marca a mensagem como enviada
UPDATE @Mensagem SET enviado_em = GETDATE() WHERE id_mensagem = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução definida deve considerar que novas mensagens podem ser recebidas na tabela ao mesmo tempo que o processo de enviar mensagens é disparado ou esteja em execução. Ou seja, é preciso diferenciar as linhas que já foram selecionadas para envio das que entraram na tabela depois que o processo de envio iniciou. O ideal seria acrescentar coluna na tabela que indicasse a situação da mensagem. Algo como "A" (aguardando envio), "S" (selecionada para envio), "E" (enviada) e "R" (erro no envio); talvez alguma outra situação que julgue necessária ser registrada. Desta forma já reduziria a possibilidade de que uma mesma mensagem fosse enviada mais de uma vez. Entretanto, como não pode alterar a estrutura da tabela, isto terá que ser simulado de outra forma. Uma opção é utilizar a coluna `enviado_em`, com os seguintes valores:

- NULL: mensagem aguardando ser enviada;
- 0: mensagem selecionada para envio;
- -1: erro no envio da mensagem;
- *outro valor*: mensagem enviada.

Para obter a lista de mensagens a enviar, e ao mesmo tempo atualizar a situação das linhas selecionadas, sugiro que utilize a instrução UPDATE em conjunto com a cláusula OUTPUT.

```
-- código #1
UPDATE Mensagem
  set enviado_em= 0
  output INSERTED.id_mensagem, 
         INSERTED.destinatario, 
         INSERTED.assunto, 
         INSERTED.mensagem
  where enviado_em is null;
```

A seguir pode iniciar o envio do conjunto de mensagens retornado pela execução do código #1 ou então disparar *threads* de envio, repassando para cada uma um subconjunto das mensagens. O número de *threads* bem como os subconjuntos são definidos de forma dinâmica no programa em #C, dependendo da quantidade de mensagens a enviar. Ou seja, basta uma única chamada no Cron.

Quanto à marcação das mensagens enviadas, há algumas abordagens. Uma delas é que, após o envio de cada mensagem a situação seja atualizada no banco de dados pela *thread*, utilizando para isto o valor de id_mensagem para localizar a linha a ser atualizada. Se a mensagem foi enviada, eis sugestão de código:

```
-- código #2
UPDATE Mensagem
  set enviado_em= current_timestamp
 where id_mensagem= @id;
```

Outra é que cada *thread*, ao final, informe ao corpo principal do programa quais mensagens foram enviadas e quais não, ficando sobre responsabilidade do corpo principal atualizar a situação das mensagens na tabela.

Answer (score -1):

Uma abordagem que resolve é a realização do calculo do resto da divisão entre uma constante única e a quantidade de chamadas que serão realizadas, gerando assim um número inteiro que agrupa os resultados.

No exemplo abaixo, a constante utilizada é a coluna de auto-incremento, pois gera um valor único para cada linha:

```
DECLARE @Mensagem TABLE (
    id_mensagem INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    criado_em DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    destinatário VARCHAR(250),
    assunto VARCHAR(250),
    mensagem VARCHAR(MAX),
    enviado_em DATETIME
);

INSERT @Mensagem
    (destinatário, assunto, mensagem)
VALUES
    ('teste1@teste.com', 'Assnto 1 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste2@teste.com', 'Assnto 2 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste3@teste.com', 'Assnto 3 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste4@teste.com', 'Assnto 4 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste5@teste.com', 'Assnto 5 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste6@teste.com', 'Assnto 6 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste7@teste.com', 'Assnto 7 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste8@teste.com', 'Assnto 8 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste9@teste.com', 'Assnto 9 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste10@teste.com', 'Assnto 10 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste11@teste.com', 'Assnto 11 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste12@teste.com', 'Assnto 12 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste13@teste.com', 'Assnto 13 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste14@teste.com', 'Assnto 14 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste15@teste.com', 'Assnto 15 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste16@teste.com', 'Assnto 16 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste17@teste.com', 'Assnto 17 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste18@teste.com', 'Assnto 18 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste19@teste.com', 'Assnto 19 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste20@teste.com', 'Assnto 20 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste21@teste.com', 'Assnto 21 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste22@teste.com', 'Assnto 22 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste23@teste.com', 'Assnto 23 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste24@teste.com', 'Assnto 24 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste25@teste.com', 'Assnto 25 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste26@teste.com', 'Assnto 26 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste27@teste.com', 'Assnto 27 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste28@teste.com', 'Assnto 28 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste29@teste.com', 'Assnto 29 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum'),
    ('teste30@teste.com', 'Assnto 30 Lorem Ipsum', 'Mensagem Lorem Ipsum');

-- Seleciona os registros não enviados apenas para uma determinada chamada
SELECT
    (M.id_mensagem % 3) + 1 AS chamada,
    M.id_mensagem,
    M.criado_em,
    M.destinatário,
    M.assunto,
    M.mensagem,
    M.enviado_em
FROM
    @Mensagem AS M
WHERE
    M.enviado_em IS NULL
    AND (M.id_mensagem % 3) + 1 = 1;-- Aqui entra o número da chamada, neste exemplo seria 1, 2 ou 3
```

Quais outras abordagens podem resolver este problema?